# Initializing fields of a structure

Tags: c, macros, initialization, structure

I'm working on a hash table assignment and I'm getting an unexpected error when trying to initialize my structure variables with a macro value. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "symTable.h"
#define DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE 61
#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599

typedef struct Node
{
    char *key;
    int *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node_T;

typedef struct SymTable
{
    Node_T **Table;
    int tablesize = DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE; //where I am getting my error
    int counter = 1;
} *SymTable_T;
```

and the error I am getting is

```
error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
```

Can someone explain to me why it isn't accepting my macro value?

Comment: This is C. You cannot assign values in a structure definition.

Comment: @Olaf is there a way to initialize them globally?

Comment: See @cad's answer. You cannot provide some "default initialiser", however. If you need such, use an init-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use an assignment in the definition of `struct SymTable`. This is a structure, i.e. a kind of type. You can't assign a value to a type, or to a part of a type: a type isn't a piece of storage, it's a classification of storage.

You can use an assignment when defining an object of type `struct SymTable`. You can assign all the fields; if you omit some fields, the fields you omit will be initialized to “zero” (meaning `0` for integer fields, `0.0` for floating point fields, `NULL` for pointer fields).

```
struct SymTable syms1 = {NULL, DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, 1};
struct SymTable syms2 = {.counter = 1, .tablesize = DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE};
```

The syntax I used for `syms2` was introduced in C99, which is supported by most but not all common compilers). The syntax I used for `syms1` has existed since the dawn of time; it has the downside that you need to provide values for the fields in order.

If you were trying to provide default values for any new object of type `struct symTable`, this is not a feature that C provides natively. A `struct symTable` declared by just writing `struct symTable somename;` in a function has uninitialized content, and there's nothing you can do about it. You can do it via a macro, but you'll need to call the macro explicitly when you create an object.

```
#define STRUCT_SYMTABLE_DEFAULT {NULL, DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, 1}
…
struct symTable syms3 = STRUCT_SYMTABLE_DEFAULT;
```

This approach has some downsides: you can only use this to initialize a struct, you can't use this syntax to assign a value later. Also, there's no type checking. A way to fix these defects is to return a value from a function. Good compilers will optimize it to the same code.

```
struct symTable inline symTable_default(void) {
    struct symTable default = {NULL, DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, 1};
    return default;
}
…
struct symTable syms4 = symTable_default();
…
/* Reset the table to its default value */
syms4 = symTable_default();
```

Answer (score 3):

You try to initialize a member in a `struct` **definition**, which is a **type**<sup>1</sup>. That's **no** variable definition and doesn't take up any memory at runtime, mind you. You don't define any variable at all, so there's nothing to initialize.

When actually defining a variable you can do something similar by using a [*designated initializer list*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

```
struct SymTable table = { .tablesize = DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, .counter = 1 };
```

This feature is only available since C99, however (GCC implements it as a **non-conformant extension since C90!**). Another, < C99 way, would be the somewhat bulkier

```
struct SymTable table = { NULL, DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, 1 };
```

where you need to know the order of members **and** the default values of each member.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @M.M for that neat wording!</sub>

Comment: I am not working with C99 afaik. Is there another way to globally initialize the members?

Comment: @donutjuice What do you mean by "globally"? I added something to my answer, maybe this'll help you.

Comment: so that the variable can be used in each of my functions. For the solutions you provided, would I make that statement inside of the structure or after it?

Comment: After it. A `struct` definition can only contain uninitialized data definitions, **no** default initializations.

Comment: @donutjuice a struct definition defines a type, not a variable. Your posted code does not have any variables in it.

Comment: @M.M Oh, nice wording, the first sentence. I plagiarized somewhat if you don't mind. :-)